# Как переопределить css стили шаблона?

Tags: wordpress

Скачал шаблон с themeforest. Столкнулся с проблемой, что стилевой файл который отвечает за цвета, и шрифты в шаблоне, закрыт для редактирования (Compiled file/Do not edit). Каким образом можно переопределить стилевое оформление?

Comment: подключить свои файлы стилей, или создать свою тему с шаблонами другой темы

Comment: вроде он не закрыт, а просто минифицирован. можно прямо в него свои стили дописать

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Путь к файлу через инспектор кода выглядит как: school_time_options_style.css?ver=4.7.5. Отдельно такой же файл лежит в папке uploads только без окончания ?ver=4.7.5. Но на изменения в нем шаблон никак не реагирует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

school_time_options_style.css - это и есть ваш искомый файл стилей.
То что он подключается с параметром, например, school_time_options_style.css?ver=4.7.5 нормально.

Если вы вносите изменения в файл, но в браузере они не отображаются, то возможно причина в кешировании страницы (в браузере, если запускаете локальную копию, а может и на сервере, если вы его подключили к какой-то CMS, например вордпрессу).

Для сброса браузерного кеша стоит использовать ctrl+F5 и/или указание собственного значения параметра в подключении скрипта, например, school_time_options_style.css?ver=4.7.6. Тогда браузер будет думать, что это новый файл и загрузит его принудительно.

Так же вы можете просто написать свои стили и подключить их после тех, что подключены в шаблоне.

Comment: Спасибо! Вся проблема была в кешировании. Даже и предполагать не мог